# Auto populating the columns in jqGrid and jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have some JSON data coming from a service. I don't know the exact format of JSON object, but i know that it's returning an array. How to auto populating the columns of a jqGrid without specifying the colModel property from this array?

Comment: You should specify more exactly the format of the JSON data returned from the service. The information that it's an array of rows is not enough.

Comment: True. So, we have creating a JSON object for colModel dynamically. We made it to work. Thanks Oleg!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to create colModel and add it to the grid dynamically.

Thanks to Oleg for suggesting the answer.